# Show 2 Additional Rows After Each Button Click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am a fan of Google Images, and I am attempting to do something similar to their search results page. Using Bootstrap 3, I am trying to only show the first two rows of an image gallery. Below the Gallery, I have an "Additional Images" button that should show only the next two rows after each click. I've gotten fairly close, but it's not exact and I can't seem to find a clear solution anywhere. Here is the code that I have for the gallery.

```
<!-- gallery carousel -->
<section id="sc_galleryCarousel">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                        <h1>Image Gallery</h1>
                        <p class="lead">Description of Gallery</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed eaque perspiciatis est quod labore minima quia delectus dolorem voluptas vero magni laudantium, praesentium error harum impedit quae, illum laborum cupiditate!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- first row of images -->
                <div class="row imageRow">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                        <div class="image-wrapper">
                            <a href="http://dummyimage.com/800x600/f2f2f2/606060&text=GalleryImage1" data-title="Image 1" data-lightbox="Rocket Launch">
                                <img src="http://dummyimage.com/320/f2f2f2/606060&text=GalleryImage" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                                <div class="image-overlay-content">
                                    <div class="content-box">
                                        <div class="inside-content-box">
                                            <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-3x"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                        <div class="image-wrapper">
                            <a href="http://dummyimage.com/800x600/f2f2f2/606060&text=GalleryImage2" data-title="Image 2" data-lightbox="Rocket Launch">
                                <img src="http://dummyimage.com/320/f2f2f2/606060&text=GalleryImage" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                                <div class="image-overlay-content">
                                    <div class="content-box">
                                        <div class="inside-content-box">
                                            <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-3x"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                        <div class="image-wrapper">
                            <a href="http://dummyimage.com/800x600/f2f2f2/606060&text=GalleryImage3" data-title="Image 3" data-lightbox="Rocket Launch">
                                <img src="http://dummyimage.com/320/f2f2f2/606060&text=GalleryImage" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                                <div class="image-overlay-content">
                                    <div class="content-box">
                                        <div class="inside-content-box">
                                            <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-3x"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                        <div class="image-wrapper">
                            <a href="http://dummyimage.com/800x600/f2f2f2/606060&text=GalleryImage4" data-title="Image 4" data-lightbox="Rocket Launch">
                                <img src="http://dummyimage.com/320/f2f2f2/606060&text=GalleryImage" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                                <div class="image-overlay-content">
                                    <div class="content-box">
                                        <div class="inside-content-box">
                                            <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-3x"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- second row of images -->
                <div class="row imageRow">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                        <div class="image-wrapper">
                            <a href="http://dummyimage.com/800x600/f2f2f2/606060&text=GalleryImage5" data-title="Image 5" data-lightbox="Rocket Launch">
                                <img src="http://dummyimage.com/320/f2f2f2/606060&text=GalleryImage" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                                <div class="image-overlay-content">
                                    <div class="content-box">
                                        <div class="inside-content-box">
                                            <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-3x"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                        <div class="image-wrapper">
                            <a href="http://dummyimage.com/800x600/f2f2f2/606060&text=GalleryImage6" data-title="Image 6" data-lightbox="Rocket Launch">
                                <img src="http://dummyimage.com/320/f2f2f2/606060&text=GalleryImage" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                                <div class="image-overlay-content">
                                    <div class="content-box">
                                        <div class="inside-content-box">
                                            <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-3x"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                        <div class="image-wrapper">
                            <a href="http://dummyimage.com/800x600/f2f2f2/606060&text=GalleryImage7" data-title="Image 7" data-lightbox="Rocket Launch">
                                <img src="http://dummyimage.com/320/f2f2f2/606060&text=GalleryImage" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                                <div class="image-overlay-content">
                                    <div class="content-box">
                                        <div class="inside-content-box">
                                            <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-3x"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                        <div class="image-wrapper">
                            <a href="http://dummyimage.com/800x600/f2f2f2/606060&text=GalleryImage8" data-title="Image 8" data-lightbox="Rocket Launch">
                                <img src="http://dummyimage.com/320/f2f2f2/606060&text=GalleryImage" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                                <div class="image-overlay-content">
                                    <div class="content-box">
                                        <div class="inside-content-box">
                                            <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-3x"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- third row of images -->
                <div class="row imageRow">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                        <div class="image-wrapper">
                            <a href="http://dummyimage.com/800x600/f2f2f2/606060&text=GalleryImage9" data-title="Image 9" data-lightbox="Rocket Launch">
                                <img src="http://dummyimage.com/320/f2f2f2/606060&text=GalleryImage" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                                <div class="image-overlay-content">
                                    <div class="content-box">
                                        <div class="inside-content-box">
                                            <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-3x"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                        <div class="image-wrapper">
                            <a href="http://dummyimage.com/800x600/f2f2f2/606060&text=GalleryImage10" data-title="Image 10" data-lightbox="Rocket Launch">
                                <img src="http://dummyimage.com/320/f2f2f2/606060&text=GalleryImage" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                                <div class="image-overlay-content">
                                    <div class="content-box">
                                        <div class="inside-content-box">
                                            <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-3x"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                        <div class="image-wrapper">
                            <a href="http://dummyimage.com/800x600/f2f2f2/606060&text=GalleryImage11" data-title="Image 11" data-lightbox="Rocket Launch">
                                <img src="http://dummyimage.com/320/f2f2f2/606060&text=GalleryImage" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                                <div class="image-overlay-content">
                                    <div class="content-box">
                                        <div class="inside-content-box">
                                            <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-3x"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                        <div class="image-wrapper">
                            <a href="http://dummyimage.com/800x600/f2f2f2/606060&text=GalleryImage12" data-title="Image 12" data-lightbox="Rocket Launch">
                                <img src="http://dummyimage.com/320/f2f2f2/606060&text=GalleryImage" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                                <div class="image-overlay-content">
                                    <div class="content-box">
                                        <div class="inside-content-box">
                                            <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-3x"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- fourth row of images -->
                <div class="row imageRow">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                        <div class="image-wrapper">
                            <a href="http://dummyimage.com/800x600/f2f2f2/606060&text=GalleryImage9" data-title="Image 9" data-lightbox="Rocket Launch">
                                <img src="http://dummyimage.com/320/f2f2f2/606060&text=GalleryImage" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                                <div class="image-overlay-content">
                                    <div class="content-box">
                                        <div class="inside-content-box">
                                            <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-3x"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                        <div class="image-wrapper">
                            <a href="http://dummyimage.com/800x600/f2f2f2/606060&text=GalleryImage10" data-title="Image 10" data-lightbox="Rocket Launch">
                                <img src="http://dummyimage.com/320/f2f2f2/606060&text=GalleryImage" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                                <div class="image-overlay-content">
                                    <div class="content-box">
                                        <div class="inside-content-box">
                                            <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-3x"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                        <div class="image-wrapper">
                            <a href="http://dummyimage.com/800x600/f2f2f2/606060&text=GalleryImage11" data-title="Image 11" data-lightbox="Rocket Launch">
                                <img src="http://dummyimage.com/320/f2f2f2/606060&text=GalleryImage" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                                <div class="image-overlay-content">
                                    <div class="content-box">
                                        <div class="inside-content-box">
                                            <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-3x"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                        <div class="image-wrapper">
                            <a href="http://dummyimage.com/800x600/f2f2f2/606060&text=GalleryImage12" data-title="Image 12" data-lightbox="Rocket Launch">
                                <img src="http://dummyimage.com/320/f2f2f2/606060&text=GalleryImage" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                                <div class="image-overlay-content">
                                    <div class="content-box">
                                        <div class="inside-content-box">
                                            <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-3x"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- fifth row of images -->
                <div class="row imageRow">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                        <div class="image-wrapper">
                            <a href="http://dummyimage.com/800x600/f2f2f2/606060&text=GalleryImage9" data-title="Image 9" data-lightbox="Rocket Launch">
                                <img src="http://dummyimage.com/320/f2f2f2/606060&text=GalleryImage" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                                <div class="image-overlay-content">
                                    <div class="content-box">
                                        <div class="inside-content-box">
                                            <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-3x"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                        <div class="image-wrapper">
                            <a href="http://dummyimage.com/800x600/f2f2f2/606060&text=GalleryImage10" data-title="Image 10" data-lightbox="Rocket Launch">
                                <img src="http://dummyimage.com/320/f2f2f2/606060&text=GalleryImage" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                                <div class="image-overlay-content">
                                    <div class="content-box">
                                        <div class="inside-content-box">
                                            <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-3x"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                        <div class="image-wrapper">
                            <a href="http://dummyimage.com/800x600/f2f2f2/606060&text=GalleryImage11" data-title="Image 11" data-lightbox="Rocket Launch">
                                <img src="http://dummyimage.com/320/f2f2f2/606060&text=GalleryImage" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                                <div class="image-overlay-content">
                                    <div class="content-box">
                                        <div class="inside-content-box">
                                            <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-3x"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                        <div class="image-wrapper">
                            <a href="http://dummyimage.com/800x600/f2f2f2/606060&text=GalleryImage12" data-title="Image 12" data-lightbox="Rocket Launch">
                                <img src="http://dummyimage.com/320/f2f2f2/606060&text=GalleryImage" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                                <div class="image-overlay-content">
                                    <div class="content-box">
                                        <div class="inside-content-box">
                                            <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-3x"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- additional rows button -->
                <div class="row additionalRows">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                        <a href="#" class="btn button-primary" id="moreImagesBtn"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down"></i>Additional Images</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Here is the jQuery that I am utilizing thus far after calling jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    var imageRowCount = $('.imageRow').length;
    if (imageRowCount >= 3){
        $('.container').children('.imageRow:nth-child(n+4)').hide();
        $('#moreImagesBtn').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.imageRow:nth-child(n+4)').nextAll(':lt(2)').slideDown().fadeIn().show();
        });
    }
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
//hid all but the first two rows
$('.imageRow:gt(1)').hide()

//on click show the first two hidden rows
$('#moreImagesBtn').click(function(){
    $('.imageRow').not(':visible').slice(0,2 ).show();
})
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/x34oqpuf/)